# How to get data with mongoose from js output?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

Here having a problem with mongoose...
I'm working on blog website and tried to use quilljs. The problem is that i have output of the file from js file where are the configs of my quill.

```js
  var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
    modules: {
        toolbar: [
            [{ header: [1, 2, false] }],
      ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
      ['image', 'code-block']
        ]
    },
    theme: 'snow'
  });
  
  $('#saveArticle').click(function(){
    quill.root.innerHTML; //output
  });
```

and how could I connect that output to my mongoose. Before that i used  tag.

```js
app.post("/compose", function(req, res){
    const post = new Post({
        content: req.body.output,
    });

    post.save(function(err){
        if (!err){
            res.redirect("/");
        }
      });
});

app.get("/blogs/:postName", function(req, res){
    const requestedPostId = req.params.postId;

    Post.findOne({_id: requestedPostId}, function(err, post){
    res.render("article", {
      content: post.content
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you are trying to send the output data to the server, the `/compose` endpoint to be specific right?

Comment: yes i'm trying to send output to the server and the /compose is endpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send the data output to the server, you need to make a post HTTP(S) request to the endpoint(`/compose`). The [browser provides a way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) of doing this, however, it seems you are already using jQuery, consequently, you can make use of the [`jQuery.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) API provided by jQuery. To send the data to the `/compose` endpoint with ajax, your code should be something like this:

```
$('#saveArticle').click(function(){
  const output = quill.root.innerHTML;
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/compose',
    data: output,
    success: function (response){
      console.log(response);
      // Whatever you want to do after successful post
      // For example, alerting that the article is saved
      alert('Article saved');
    },
    error: function(err){
      // Whatever you want to do after a failed post
      console.error(err);
    }
  });
});
```